Setting up Prometheus on Azure Kubernetes Cluster
I am setting up Prometheus on a production aks cluster. The app deployment on this cluster is exposed using ngnix ingress behind a load balancer and a firewall device.
How do I access Prometheus dashboard from this cluster, I am quite new to it and dont want to use AKS Managed Prometheus due to costs. All I could find documentation is using port forwarding technique to local host.
I dont want to expose the Prometheus dashboard using same nginx ingress to avoid unauthorized access. Any suggestions?
I have gone through the documentation from official source: promitor.io
But it says: "Run kubectl port-forward svc/promitor-agent-scraper 8080:80 and check" But I cant do that in production
